# phpMyAdmin No activity within 1440 seconds; please log in again. Issue

Tags: centos, php, session, phpmyadmin

I have installed latest phpMyAdmin on Apache+php+mysql on CentOs.

But after sometime of inactivity i am getting

**No activity within 1440 seconds; please log in again.**

And redirected to the phpMyAdmin Log-In page.

I have Edited /etc/php.ini 
and set

**session.gc_maxlifetime    999999**

and did HTTPD restart.

But still i am getting the same error.
How do i fix this ?

How do i make the phpMyAdmin session for like 20+ days, as its a production environment.

Thanks

===========================================================================================

my phpinfo session is as

```
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off Off
session.bug_compat_warn Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  999999  999999
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php/session    /var/lib/php/session
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: For a better answer, see http://www.lanredahunsi.net/how-to-increase-phpmyadmin-session-timeout-from-1440-seconds/

Comment: A detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/phpmyadmin-no-activity-within-1440-seconds-please-login/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same problem has been annoying me for weeks, but I think that I now have the answer, at least for the latest versions of phpMyAdmin (I currently have version 4.1.14). You need to change settings->features->Login cookie validity. The way that you get to this setting is as follows:

```
1) Login to phpMyAdmin
2) From the home screen click on "More settings" (middle bottom of screen for me)
3) Click the "Features" tab/button towards the top of the screen.
4) For 20 days set the "Login cookie validity" setting to 1728000
5) Apply.
```

Hope that helps?

Comment: Cannot load or save configuration
Please create web server writable folder config in phpMyAdmin top level directory as described in documentation. Otherwise you will be only able to download or display it.
Will it make problem?